# change ereg_replace into preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

It seems to be simple, but I have problem.

```
ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row)
```

into preg_replace.

Anyone could give me a hand?

Comment: Also explained in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php#98602

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you need to change (except function name) is to add delimiters to the pattern (slashes in this case):

```
preg_replace("/\n/", "\\n", $row);
```

However, in this particular case you do not need to use regexes (which are slow enough), simple [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would be fine:

```
str_replace("\n", "\\n", $row);
```